# Function for finding duration where wave height <3m where time is between 5:00am and 6:00PM

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find duration for time where wave height is under 3m and time period is between 5:00am and 6:00pm. Trying to find this duration for a month of tidal data.

I have raw data for wave height and timestamps when it is high and low.

eg.

```
Timestamp  Wave_Height
1/01/2022 3:16  0.68
1/01/2022 9:37  6.62
1/01/2022 16:14 1.07
1/01/2022 21:54 5.37
2/01/2022 4:06  0.59
```

etc…

So far I have got linear interpolation to find points where wave height=3. I am struggling to get a function to find the durations for my limits on time.
Included a picture to explain
[Graph of wave data over time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gkl9w.png)
The timestamps occur over different days in the month so difference between times must consider the changed dates in some cases(see rev 2 errors ####### where errors occur for changing of dates)

[rev 2 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVQoS.png)

Answer (score 0):

The following should work.  I have added some columns to avoid complicated formulas.

1. interpolate when the wave_height = 3 (column G)
2. add column H which is True when wave_height increases and False if it decreases (at the time in column G):
   so cell H6 `= F7<3` gives TRUE
3. add column E to limit the time window to 5:00-18:00.
   E7 is `=IF(D7<$G$2;$G$2;IF(D7>$H$2;$H$2;D7))`
4. Added column I to calculate the time during wich wave_height < 3.  The sum of that column is what you need.
   I8 is `=H8*(G8-E7)+NOT(H8)*(D8-G8)`

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the simpler format and formulas. I'm having problems still because it doesn't account for times over different dates.